# How to change default background color of callout bubble with detailCalloutAccessoryView

Tags: swift, mkmapview, mkannotation, swift3, mkannotationview

In my app I have the following sutuation.

I've implemented a custom callout bubble with custom detailCalloutAccessoryView with two labels inside.

I know how to change the color of detailCalloutAccessoryView with this line.

```
view.detailCalloutAccessoryView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
```

But I can't figure out how to change background color of the main bubble (it is transparent grey/white now). With  `view.detailCalloutAccessoryView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red`  line my calloutbubble looks like this:

[image]

But I want my custom bubble to look like this:

[image]

Here is my viewFor annotation method:

```
 func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

        if annotation is MKUserLocation {
            return nil
        }

        let identifier = "pin"
        var view : MKAnnotationView

        if let dequedView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier) {
            dequedView.annotation = annotation

            view = dequedView

        } else {
            view = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)

            view.canShowCallout = true

        }

             let pinImage = UIImage.init(named: "customPin")


        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

            view.detailCalloutAccessoryView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

        })

        view.image = pinImage

        configureDetailView(annotationView: view)
        return view
    }
```

I'm working in Xcode 8 w/ Swift 3.

It would be also interesting to know how to change font type and default black color of the title from black to another color.
In detail view i can easily change color of my custom labels in xib file but don't know how to access default title properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had created the code for your requirement please find the below url for download the code and review it.

Link : https://www.dropbox.com/s/o2howwqceq8rsgu/MapInformation.zip?dl=0

> Environment : Xcode 8 and Swift3

**Highlight the code which I had done it.**

I had taken the approach to display the Popup(`UIPresentationController`) instead of callout. For more information please find the below code.

A) I had used the `UIButton` to display as annotation on the MapView and display the popup when user click on it.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

        if annotation is MKUserLocation {
            return nil
        }

        let identifier = "pin"
        var annotationView = self.mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier) as! AnnotationView?

        if annotationView == nil {

            annotationView = AnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
            annotationView?.canShowCallout = false
        }

        else {
            annotationView?.annotation = annotation
        }

        //Take the UIButton and implement the touchupinside action for showing the popup.
        let pinImage = UIImage.init(named: "customPin")
        annotationView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: (pinImage?.size.width)!, height: (pinImage?.size.width)!)
        annotationView?.mapPin = UIButton(frame: (annotationView?.frame)!);
        annotationView?.mapPin.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.showPopup(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        annotationView?.addSubview((annotationView?.mapPin)!)
        annotationView?.mapPin.setImage(pinImage, for: .normal)

        return annotationView
    }
```

B) Display the popup when user click on the annotation.

```
func showPopup(sender: UIButton!) {

        let popupVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Popup") as? Popup
        popupVC?.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 250, height: 150)
        popupVC?.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.popover

        let rect = sender.superview?.convert(sender.frame, to: self.view)
        popupVC?.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self;
        popupVC?.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
        popupVC?.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = rect!
        popupVC?.popoverPresentationController?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

        self.present(popupVC!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

***Note***

> If you want to change the popup color from red to other different
>   color then you can do only single line of coding by changing the color name.
>
> popupVC?.popoverPresentationController?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

Please look into the below screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
   func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
        
        //design your custom view and set it to detailCalloutAccessoryView

        view.detailCalloutAccessoryView = yourDetailView
        detail.superview?.superview?.backgroundColor = yourColor
        // This view is type of MKSmallCalloutView
    }
```

Comment: it worked for me but the correct code is : func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
        
        //design your custom view and set it to detailCalloutAccessoryView

        view.detailCalloutAccessoryView = yourDetailView
        detail.superview?view.detailCalloutAccessoryView.superview?.backgroundColor = yourColor
    }

Answer (score 2):

`UIViewCallout` is a private class. If you want custom callout view:

1. disable standart callout `view.canShowCallout = false`
2. implement `MKMapViewDelegate` methods with your custom `UIView` for callout:

   ```
   func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
       let redCalloutView = RedCalloutView(view.annotation)
       view.addSubview(redCalloutView)
   }

   func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didDeselect view: MKAnnotationView) {
       view.subviews.forEach {
           if $0 is RedCalloutView {
               $0.removeFromSuperview()
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    for v in view.subviews{
        if v.subviews.count > 0{
            v.subviews[0].backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        }
    }
}
```

[image: change bubble and label both color]

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    for v in view.subviews{
        if v.subviews.count > 0 {
            let colloutView = v.subviews[0]
            colloutView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 0.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 0.8)
            if colloutView.subviews.count > 0 {
                if colloutView.subviews[0].subviews.count > 0{
                    colloutView.subviews[0].subviews.forEach { (view) in
                        if let label = view as? UILabel{
                            label.textColor = UIColor.white
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This usually works well, but occasionally my selected `view` has no `subviews` yet, and it appears with the default white background color. Have you encountered this situation and worked around it?