# Add new button line to the bottom of MKPointAnnotation in swift

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkpointannotation

If it's a duplicate question then sorry for that. I researched several topics but could not find exact what i want. So I want to add several buttons as to `MKPointAnnotation`. I know how to add to left and right. But, I need as in following picture.

[image]

I would be pleased if anybody can help me.
Thank you for attention.

Comment: Please refer the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39467838/how-to-change-default-background-color-of-callout-bubble-with-detailcalloutacces/39638595#39638595

Comment: Thank you. i have done with that.

Comment: Welcome buddy.....